# PySpark Control Character Delimiter not being handled/converted while reading/writing CSV

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, delimiter

As per current requirement, I want to use delimiter as ^A, ^B (control-characters on front end) etc which are getting converted to \u0001 and \u0002 on reaching the pipeline as per ideal scenario.

I tested the csv writing using \u0001 as delimiter(hard-coded), the csv is correctly parsed and stored in data frame.

[image]

Code:

`delimSrc = '\u0001'`

`df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header', True).option('delimiter',delimSrc).load('<path_to_csv>.csv')`

But when this value is being passed through JOB parameters(using `args['delimSrc']`), it is giving error.

[[image: error from cloud-watch, using Glue for Pyspark job1]

Even I tried to extract the type of this `args['delimSrc']`using below code and found the is `str(string)`

`print (type(delimSource))`

[image]

What wrong is happening when job param is being passed breaking the job while hard-coded value is working. Also, what should be done to convert/pass so that it parse csv using the job parameter. Please help.

Comment: Could you please put all the details such as python version, on which operating system you are trying this, Spark version.
this will help to understand the problem statement.
Also, put the complete pyspark code and the command which you are using to run the program.